# C++ Get/Change permission of a folder and file?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, permissions

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 on Windows 10 RS5.
I intend to make an explorer which shows functions of standard explorer and permissions, like this

---

```
No  Name            Create              Permission
1   Application     18/01/21 - 11:00    rw
2   Privacy         18/01/21 - 10:00    --
3   Protected       18/01/20 - 09:01    r-
```

---

I implemented this using `_taccess()`, but is there any function to get permission of a file or folder on `Kernel32.dll` or `ntdll.dll`? 
Then, how can I change the permission using `WinAPI`.

**Permission:**

> r: Read-able
>   w: Write-able

I cannot find out valid answer on here, so I posted it.  The main point is get permission not using `_taccess()`, and change permission using `WinAPI`.

Comment: See [GetFileAttributesExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw)

Comment: Ah! @KenWhite, thank you so much! but in case of a directory?

Comment: @Alexander It works on directories, too. But it doesn't give you permissions like you are looking for, other than read-only. You really shoud be using [`GetNamedSecurityInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfow) and [`AccessCheck()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-accesscheck) instead. Windows has a very different permissions model than 'Nix systems.

Comment: Check explorer security tab to see what you should display.

Comment: Readonly is not a permission. It means literally that a file is set in stone. Some authority may grant us permission to move an immovable rock, but we still can't move it. Along similar lines, the [i]immutable file attribute in Unix systems is separate from file write permissions, even if it factors into the `W_OK` `access` check.

Comment: Most implementations of `chmod` for DOS/Windows file systems conflate these two concepts by mixing up write permission with the readonly file attribute. This  includes the FAT32 implementation on Linux and WSL's drvfs. I've only seen Linux ntfs-3g get this right. `chmod` should be a no-op if the filesystem doesn't support security or we can't map the Windows security descriptor (owner, group, DACL, SACL mandatory label) to Unix owner, group, and other permission bits. ntfs-3g implements this in Linux with a user mapping.

Comment: Using `AccessCheck` is complicated in itself, but also because we have to evaluate the parent directory for `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` access to determine whether `DELETE` access is granted and for `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` to determine whether `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` is granted. The parent directory overrides security set on the file itself. Typically it should suffice to call `CreateFile` to check access, which also tells you whether access is denied due to file data-access (read, write, delete) sharing. But note that `CreateFile` always requests at least `SYNCHRONIZE` and `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access.